# VB/C# Group objects by key - performance (memory) problem

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, performance, logging

I am reading from a log file.

My target is to display the 10 most popular requested URL's of a website.

One way to do this is to read all log entries and save each URL to a Dictionary. The dictionary has the URL as the Key and the number of visits as the Value. If a URL exists in the dictionary the Value of that URL's Key is increased +1, otherwise a new Key/Value pair is added with a value of 1.

Once the processing is finished the dictionary is sorted by Value and the top 10 entries are shown.

This might work, however it could cause a serious memory problem when dealing with a log file of a website which has thousands of different page url's (think query strings).

Since I only need the top 10 entries, is there a way to avoid placing all the URL's into memory and still get the top 10 URL + Visits count?

Comment: Write it using the dictionary if it doesn't work then rewrite it.

Comment: I agree, you should try it first. Even if there are tens of thousands of URLs and each is very long, it would in worst case consume like a couple megabytes of memory - and that only for a few moments...

Comment: I've heard that Google uses this as an interview question.

Comment: So whats the answer then hehe? I already did this it, works, i am just concerned about memory usage, maybe someone could give me worst-case scenario memory usage numbers?

Comment: See my edit for sample numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not cause serious memory problems for most sane data sets.
Unless you work for Google, you won't have any memory issues.
Premature optimization is evil.

If, after you implement it simply, you have memory issues, you should switch to a SQL database.

**EDIT**: (in response to your comment)
10,000 different 500-character strings will use 10,000 * 500 * 4 bytes = 20MB, which is very little.  (It will also use bit more for string housekeeping and for the dictionary itself, but that will be less than 1MB total)
Until you start getting millions of *unique* 500-character URLs, you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an accurate chart of the top 10 urls, no.
But, what you can do is sampling, or get rid of pages that have no chance of making it to the top 10, for example, caching each page's visits for a day and only tracking the top 100 pages, other then that, you'd need to store the visits for each page.

Answer (score 0):

If you can fit it all into one dictionary, do that.

...But let's assume that your log file has too many URLs to fit into a single Dictionary.

1. Split the logfile in half.
2. Put the first half of the logfile into Dictionary0 as you described, so that you have `Dict0(URL) = count`.
3. Now reverse that dictionary and sort it so that you have `RevDict0(Count) = {URL0,URL1,...}`

In VB.Net, here's how to reverse the dictionary:

```
Dim RevDict0 as Dictionary(of Integer, List(of String))
For Each url as String in Dict0
    If Not RevDict0.Contains(Dict0(url)) Then
        RevDict0.Add(Dict0(url), new List(of String))
    End If
    RevDict0(Dict0(url)).Add(url)
Next
```

Now look at the 11th index of RevDict0, `RevDict0.Keys.Sort.Reverse.item(11)`.  For example, let's say that number is 90.  Now close the logfile and dictionaries to free memory and start again with the second half of the logfile to make Dict1 and RevDict1.  Examine `RevDict1.Keys.Sort.Reverse.Item(11)`.  Let's assume that number is 40.  Now we know that any URL in the first half with less than 50 visits that isn't in the top-ten of the second half can't have more than 90 visits (50+40) so it can't possibly be in the final top-ten.

Now we free everything except the top-ten of the `RevDict1`.

Now:

1. Build `FinalDict(of String, Integer)` using the first half of the logfile (or read from disk if you stored Dict0 earlier).
2. Remove from `FinalDict` anything with less than 50 visits that isn't in RevDict1, to free memory.
3. Add to `FinalDict` using the second half of the logfile.

Notes:

- You end up doing multiple passes but you never have the URLs in memory.
- It only saves memory if the 11th indicies (90 and 40) are far enough apart that you can free a lot of `FinalDict` members.
- If it turns out the the 11th index of the second half is bigger than the first (40 and 90 instead of 90 and 40) then you need to read in the second half of the logfile, then the first, and use Dict1 instead of Dict0, etc.
- This is pretty clumsy; there must be something smarter!